A few questions about Priddy’s construction of $BP$
In A Cellular Construction of BP and Other Irreducible Spectra, Priddy gives an interesting approach to constructing the Brown-Peterson spectrum $BP$. His result is often summarized as

If you start with the spectrum $\mathbb S_{(p)}$ and iteratively cone off generators of the odd-dimensional homotopy, starting from the lowest degree, you get $BP$.

Question 1: How does a statement of the above “purely stable” form follow from Priddy’s paper? It seems to me that he rather constructs a sequence of spaces which he calls $X_n$, and then strings them together into a spectrum by hand. The spaces $X_n$ are indeed constructed by iteratively coning off odd-dimensional homotopy, but it’s an unstable construction which is lifted to the stable homotopy category by hand.
Question 2: What does Priddy mean when he says [1] that the spectrum $X$ (which he is showing to be equivalent to $BP$) is a “ring spectrum with unit”? He indicates that a multiplication map $X \otimes X \to X$ can be constructed by obstruction theory, but does he intend to assert that this map is homotopy associative / commutative? If so, how does one see this? It seems to me that you can’t argue for this just by obstruction theory using evenness.
Question 3: In the “second proof” of the Lemma to Theorem (i), Priddy asserts that the map $X^p \to X$ extends to $X^p_{h\Sigma_p} \to X$ by obstruction theory. First, what is the map $X^p \to X$? If we don’t know the multiplication is associative (cf. Question 2) then are we choosing a particular parenthesization of the multiplication? Second, why does it extend? I agree with Priddy’s assertion that $X^p_{h\Sigma_p}$ has even cells, but it seems to me that the map $X^p \to X^p_{h \Sigma_p}$ is not injective on $\mathbb F_p$ homology — I think in order to extend, we need to know something about the commutativity of the multiplication (cf. Question 2 again) (as well as something about the associativity).
[1] this statement is right after the statement of Theorem (i) at the beginning of Section 2, bottom of p. 31, which is page 3 of the pdf

re Question 2: he just means that there is a map $X \otimes X \to X$ whose restriction to $(S^0\otimes X) \oplus (X \otimes S^0)$ is the fold.

Q3: Any order multiplication is ok. But the obstruction theory part is an actual issue, and I think an error - you want to say the relevant cohomology groups vanish because they have coefficients in something zero or torsion-free, but torsion-freeness sort of assumes what you are trying to prove (ie the existence of BP). The way around this is to do the construction piece-meal: extend the map enough to build the next power operation, use it to get torsion-freeness, and then continue.

If you actually do that, you'll realize that you didn't need power operations anyway and you'll just end up doing a sort of cellular version of the original construction of BP (ie check that the comodule structure looks okay in a range, then name the next attaching map in Priddy's construction using the Adams sseq, and then attach it and check the comodule structure looks right in a larger range.)

I agree with Dylan, it's certainly possible to make choices of multiplication that are not homotopy commutative or associative. Probably it is easier to start with a map $D_3 BP \to BP$ that you can construct by obstruction theory, and then restrict it to $BP \wedge BP \wedge S^0$, so that the result is homotopy commutative associative.

Re Q1, you can build spaces $Y_n$ inductively by starting with $\Sigma Y_{n-1}$ and then only attaching cells to kill off homotopy in the stable range. That makes a spectrum $Y$ which is the stable construction you have been told about. Then $X_n$ can be built from $Y_n$ by attaching higher cells, and you can construct a map of spectra $Y \to X$ that's an isomorphism in homotopy.

@TylerLawson If we do as you say, and construct $f: D_3 BP \to BP$ which we then restrict to $m = f i : BP \otimes BP \otimes S \to BP$, then I agree that $m$ is homotopy commutative, but I don’t see why it should be associative. I’m also not sure how to construct $f$ when $p = 2$ (although there’s a lot about the procedure which confuses me in this case)

@TimCampion You're correct, that won't handle composition. Sorry!
